# Selected item in ng-options is not displayed in case items are loaded with timeout

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have a stored item value (in local storage), but items collection is loaded from server each time - no need to store it on client side. When the items collection is loaded from server, I want my stored item to be displayed in dropdown list. Here is simplified version of what I have:

**controller:**

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .controller("DemoCtrl", function($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.items = [];
        $scope.item = "Two";
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.items = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
    }, 1000);
});
```

**markup:**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl"> 
        <select ng-model="item" ng-options="item for item in items">
            <option value="">---</option>
        </select>
        {{ item }}
    </div>
</body>
```

Little [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3Ig798ipaPq6HMtMW1zE?p=preview) where you can see, that after 1 second delay, the value is not displayed in dropdown - just a blank space. I've looked at markup and it seems to be ok:

```
...
<option value="1" selected="selected" label="Two">Two</option>
...
```

So the value was selected, but just not displaying for some reason.

I've tried to take different versions of Angular and it seems like this behavior is appearing in 1.3.XXX versions: previous (1.2) and next (1.4-beta) versions work fine.

I don't want to downgrade to 1.2, and 1.4 is still in beta, so I've figured out a workaround for this - if I change `ng-options` a little bit:

```
ng-options="item for item in items track by item"
```

It starts working as it should. But I still would like to know, what is the reason of this weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Wait to set the selected item until the array is populated like this:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("DemoCtrl", function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.items = [];
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.items = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
        $scope.item = "Two";
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: The problem is I have multiple such collections of different items, and multiple stored selected values. Server collections and restored values are loaded separately in different services.

Comment: You could have a watch on items and item and update item on any change. Not pretty but would work until you can update to 1.4

Comment: Yeah, I could. But I already have a workaround with `track by` - it's much simpler. Just strange that this issue doesn't exist in 1.2 and 1.4...